# Android API to Connect to Wifi Network

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, android-developer-api

I'm totaly lost in the versions of WiFi APIs.
I want to connect to a configured WiFi Network programmaticaly.
As decribed in this question:
[Connect to wifi network Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691846/connect-to-wifi-network-android-programmatically)

I develop on Android 10 and want to write a code that is also compatible with older Android Versions.

On my android 10 the code described does not work.
What code do I need to implement the functionality on Android 10?

What do I do to write an application that also runs on my other Android 9 phone?

Regards Jürgen

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753528/creating-a-custom-wifi-setup/59755390#59755390

Answer (score 6):

From Android Q, connecting to Wifi Network has changes a lot.

First of all the code you are using or @matdev mentioned uses API `public int addNetwork (WifiConfiguration config)` from `WifiManager` is deprecated in Android 10 and will return -1 as networkID.

From Android Q, two classes are suggested for Wifi connection. But each of them has its own advantage and disadvantage.

```
1. WifiNetworkSpecifier
```

A code example from WifiUtil Library

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(scanResult.SSID)
            .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString(scanResult.BSSID));

    final String security = ConfigSecurities.getSecurity(scanResult);

    ConfigSecurities.setupWifiNetworkSpecifierSecurities(wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder, security, password);


    NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.build())
            .build();

    // not sure, if this is needed
    if (networkCallback != null) {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }

    networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);

            wifiLog("AndroidQ+ connected to wifi ");

            // bind so all api calls are performed over this new network
            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable();

            wifiLog("AndroidQ+ could not connect to wifi");
        }
    };

    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
```

My observation with this implementation is - It is more like P2P communication, and at this time other application from the same device cannot use internet from the connected WiFi network

```
2. WifiNetworkSuggestion
```

A code example from developer.android.com

```
final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion1 =
  new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
  .setSsid("test111111")
  .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
  .build();

final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion2 =
  new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
  .setSsid("test222222")
  .setWpa2Passphrase("test123456")
  .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
  .build();

final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion3 =
  new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
  .setSsid("test333333")
  .setWpa3Passphrase("test6789")
  .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
  .build();

final PasspointConfiguration passpointConfig = new PasspointConfiguration();
// configure passpointConfig to include a valid Passpoint configuration

final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion4 =
  new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
  .setPasspointConfig(passpointConfig)
  .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
  .build();

final List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestionsList =
  new ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> {{
    add(suggestion1);
    add(suggestion2);
    add(suggestion3);
    add(suggestion4);
  }};

final WifiManager wifiManager =
  (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

final int status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
// do error handling here…
}

// Optional (Wait for post connection broadcast to one of your suggestions)
final IntentFilter intentFilter =
  new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION);

final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!intent.getAction().equals(
      WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
      return;
    }
    // do post connect processing here...
  }
};
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

My observation with the above mentioned implementation is, when you call the `wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions` it return success and show user a notification for connection. If the user accept, device gets connected to the WiFi network and other app can user internet. But if user disconnect from network and you call `wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions` again, it will return  `WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_ADD_DUPLICATE` error.

It looks like this API just provide a suggestion list of networks where the device can auto connect. But the connection will be determined by the OS.

But if you really need a solution, an undocumented way use to the Default Wifi QR Code Scanner from Android Source that can detect both QR Code schems Zxing and DPP.

here is an a code example :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_WIFI_QR_SCANNER && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        //WIFI Connection is Successful
    }
    else
    {
        //.......
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private void startWifiQRCodeScanner(Context context)
{
    final String INTENT_ACTION_WIFI_QR_SCANNER = "android.settings.WIFI_DPP_ENROLLEE_QR_CODE_SCANNER";
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(wifiManager.isEasyConnectSupported())
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_WIFI_QR_SCANNER);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_WIFI_QR_SCANNER);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dharman Your undocumented way is only working, if you have a qr code with wifi information, right? This way does not work when you don't want to use the qr code scanner, right?

Comment: @JulianSchweppe, yes this way will not work unless you use qr code scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution working from Android 6 (API level 23)

```
String AP_SSID = "YourWifiNetworkSSID";
String AP_PASSWORD = "YourWifiNetworkPassword";
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + AP_SSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain ssid in quotes

conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + AP_PASSWORD + "\"";

wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

try {
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + AP_SSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();

            break;
        }
    }
 } catch (SecurityException e) {
     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); 
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code. I aallready found this. the problem ist the border from version 9 to version 10 of Android. There are a lot of changes and this code will not run anymore. So does anyone have a concept o handling a cross androidversion code? Also a code for android 10 would be fine. Any Ideas??