# Android 10 Connect wifi programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to connect Specific wifi network in android 10(Android Q). Below android 10 it was working fine. I gone through some documents. Theysaid will have to use WifiNetworkSpecifier. I tried by using below code stuff.

```
 WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
                                                            builder.setSsid(ssid);
                                                            builder.setWpa2Passphrase(password);
                                                            WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
                                                            NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
                                                            networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
                                                            networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
                                                            NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
                                                            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                                            if (cm != null) {
                                                                cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                                                                        super.onAvailable(network);
                                                                        cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
```

But I am unable to connect specified network. Can anyone please guide me..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884943/2068732

Comment: Have you added permission `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` to the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have added android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE to the manifest